# show item in list view after sax xml parsing

Tags: android, xml, parsing

```
public class XMLParsingExample extends ListActivity {
String name = null;
private String array_estado[];
private String[] array_ciudad;
private String array_barrio[];
/** Create Object For SiteList Class */
SitesList sitesList = null;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listplaceholder);
    /** Create a new layout to display the view */
    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    layout.setOrientation(1);
try {

        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

        /** Send URL to parse XML Tags */
        URL sourceUrl = new URL(
                "http://www.arteonline.mobi/iphone/output.php?key=Buenos");

        MyXMLHandler myXMLHandler = new MyXMLHandler();
        xr.setContentHandler(myXMLHandler);
        xr.parse(new InputSource(sourceUrl.openStream()));

    } 
        catch (Exception e) 
       {
        System.out.println("XML Pasin");
       }
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if want to display your parsed data on ListView

for that Make a ArrayList from Parse Data and 
make a adapter from that and then set it to Your ListView

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you have a look at this example. 
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html

It should help you get an understanding of how ListActivity works.